# Job Position term

Tags: word-choice

Anyone from the corporate world, what do you call someone who talks to possible clients (or apply to jobs for a client?!), and seals the contract on the owner's behalf? Does this position exist? Lol.

Comment: This question is probably on-topic, but you're going to need to be **a lot** more descriptive of the role and what the person does. I'll put this on hold for the moment while you edit that in, so that people don't bark up the wrong tree with a job-title that only answers part of the question.

Comment: Yes. I agree with Andrew. From the information you have given it sounds nothing more nor less than a 'sales person'. But I feel sure you are looking for something other than that.

Comment: If it is the contractual side you are emphasizing then perhaps 'Commercial Manager (or Director)' who typically deals with contract negotiation. For a less specific title that is not quite the same as Sales Person, 'Business Development Manager' is now quite common and encompasses Account Management, Sales and Commercial relationship management

Answer (score 1):

**bidder** or **tenderer**

*Oxford Dictionary of English*

> ■ [no obj.] (bid for) (of a contractor) offer to do (work) for a stated price; tender for: nineteen companies have indicated their intention to bid for the contract.

**recruiter**

*Oxford Dictionary of English*

> ■ enrol (someone) as a member or worker in an organization or as a supporter of a cause: there are plans to recruit more staff later this year.